# how to concatenate data from csv without duplicating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to concatenate 4 pipe separated value data files, (itpas208,+...+, itpas212). My code follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', low_memory=False) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC_data/itpas2_data/itpas2**.txt')))
```

When I run the code I have 66 columns. I know that each file contains 22 columns. I think that I am concatenating columns instead of rows.

Comment: If the columns are not the same then the df will expand column-wise as well as row-wise

Comment: The columns aren't labeled. Should I use a names= in the read_csv command?

Comment: You mean there is no header row, if so pass header=None

Comment: It worked, but now I only have 5 rows and there should be over a million. I want the files to concatenate by row.

Comment: Try passing ignore_index =True

Comment: Thanks; ignore_index=True was giving an error so I used index_col=None and it is working!

Comment: It would help enormously if you posted a few lines of each file to avoid the confusion and ambiguity